# data binding Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a component with a variable say 'id' and in this component i'm calling a service that's take that variable(id) as parameter,
in my template I assign the value of a radio Button to the variable(id)..
the problem is ..I'm calling my Service in "ngOnInit()", so it doesn't take the value of the radio button , but takes the initial value of the "id"..
Here is my code:

in my component:

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { BartersService } from '../../core/services/barters.service'; 

 export class BarterViewComponent implements OnInit {
 id:string="";
 allCategories ;
 constructor( private barServ: BartersService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
   this.barServ.findByPage(this.id)
   .subscribe(respone => {
   this.allCategories = respone.data;
    });

    }
 onSelectionChange(val) {
  this.id = val;
 }

}
```

in my Template :

```
<div *ngFor="let cat of allCategories ; let i=index;">                              
   <input  style="margin-bottom: 10px;" type="radio" #R 
      (change)="onSelectionChange(R.value )" name="rad"  value="cat['id']"> 
      {{cat['name']}}
</div>
```

## Target:

the target is updating the view based on the selection of the radio button.

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
export class BarterViewComponent implements OnInit {
 id:string="";
 allCategories ;

 constructor( private barServ: BartersService) { }
 ngOnInit() {
    refreshCategories()
 }

 onSelectionChange(val) {
  this.id = val;
  refreshCategories()
 }

 refreshCategories() {
   this.barServ.findByPage(this.id).subscribe(respone => {
       this.allCategories = respone.data;
   });
 }
}
```

Comment: you can also pass the id as a param to refreshCategories().

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
value="cat['id']"
```

to

`[value]="cat['id']"` or `value="{{cat['id']}}"`